# Idiomatic exceptions handling in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception

Handling exceptions, I found myself needing this handy little function :

```kotlin
inline fun exec(lambda: () -> Any): Boolean = try { lambda() ; true } catch(e:Exception) { false }
```

Does functions like that exist in Kotlin ?
Is there idiomatic altenatives to the heavy try-catch-finnaly syntax ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is your use case for that? Personally I prefer exceptions over a function that just returns a `successful` boolean because different exceptions can be thrown in different error scenarios, allowing for different error handling.

Comment: This is a bad idea, for several reasons.  If an exception was thrown, how do you tell what went wrong?  Your function swallows the exception completely, without even logging it.  So there's no way to find out what exception was thrown, where it was thrown, or what message it contained.  (And if you're assuming that only one thing could possibly go wrong, you're very probably missing something…)  A function like this makes it impossible to debug coding problems, or to handle more than one type of error condition…

Comment: …It also needs (but doesn't force) the direct caller to check the return value, and either handle it there and then, or return it to _its_ caller, and so on.  Finally, it requires the lambda to return a non-nullable values, and then ignores it.

Comment: There are certain situations when interacting with Java code where it might make sense to wrap Exception-throwing code with something that just returns null on failure. But usually, you would only want to wrap the specific exceptions you're expecting like `IllegalArgumentException` and `NumberFormatException`, as a way to swallow exceptions that you don't need to log because they indicate something that you expected might happen, like if you pass user input for some kind of validation.

Comment: @vatbub It was something like that
```kotlin
val isAudio = isAudioFile(source) && exec { m.setDataSource(source.canonicalPath) }
```
setDataSource would throw if there was any problem of data avaibility

Comment: For such a usage scenario you will not find a function in the standard library - for the above reasons. However, in your case, I suggest that you rename the function. `exec` doesn't really represent the purpose of the function which is to check if the code throws an exception. I would rather name it `throws`

Comment: @vatbub I replaced the code with runCatching{}.isSuccess. That's fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `runCatching` and then use `.isSuccess` on the result to get a Boolean for success

```
runCatching {
    // your code
}.isSuccess
```

If your code needs a result, and you want to return null on failure (which is idiomatic Kotlin) you can do

```
val foo: Foo? = runCatching {
    // your code that produces a Foo
}.getOrNull()
```

Comment: `runCatching` can be a bit dangerous. If the example code above were to an `OutOfMemoryError` (or any other `java.lang.Error` that you probably shouldn't catch), it would get swallowed up. Consider using try/catch instead.